# FlinkKafkaConsumer08 offset control

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I want to use FlinkKafkaConsumer08 to read a kafka topic. The messages are commands in terms of event-sourcing. I want to start from the end, not reading messages already in the topic.
I suppose there is a way to tell FlinkKafkaConsumer08 to start from the end.
How?

## edit

I have tried setting "auto.offset.reset" property to "largest" with no result. I have tried enableCheckpoing too.

I have tried setting "auto.commit.interval.ms" to 1000. Then, at least, messages that have been previously processed are not processed again. This is a big improvements as, at least, commands are not executed twice, but it would be much better to discard old command messages. The solution I will adopt is to discard old messages based on date, and return error.

Answer (score 2):

The `auto.offset.reset` property is only used if Kafka cannot find committed offsets in Kafka/ZooKeeper for the current consumer group. Thus, if you're reusing a consumer group, this property will most likely not be respected. However, starting the Kafka consumer in a new consumer group should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal! Sure it is useful for others. Starting each time with a new kafka group.id does not fit my needs. In order to have the commands executed exactly once, I am using the group.id to exclude other applications from reading commands.